# Posterior consistency for scale-mixture shrinkage priors in low dimension?

Tags: regression, probability, bayesian, large-data, consistency

Consider the model [1]

$$y_n=X_n\beta_n+\epsilon_n$$
$$\beta_i|\sigma^2,v_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 v_i), i=1,\ldots,p$$
$$v_i \sim \beta^\prime(a,b)$$
$$\sigma^2 \sim \mathcal{IG}(c,d)$$

where $\beta^\prime$ is the beta prime distribution and $\mathcal{IG}$ the inverse gamma distribution.

In [1], the authors prove posterior consistency in the high-dimensionality regimes were $p\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Is there a way to show posterior consistency for fixed/small $p$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

[1] Bai, R. and Ghosh, M., 2021. On the beta prime prior for scale parameters in high-dimensional bayesian regression models. Statistica Sinica, 31(2), pp.843-865.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06539.pdf the authors set $f$ to be a beta prime prior and prove posterior consistency in high dimension. My question is there a similar prove for fixed/small $p$ with the same prior and or different priors?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, I think it is very familiar to anyone following the latest research of normal-scale mixture models and posterior consistency.

Comment: Rather than answering in the comments, please [edit] your question to include all of this information in the question, so the question is self-contained and people don't have to read the comments, then flag the comments as no longer needed.  Ideally, questions should be self-contained so we don't need to find and read some other paper to understand the question.  I still don't understand what $v_i \sim f(v_i)$ means or why this is not a circular definition of $v_i$.

Comment: Unless the $\beta_i$ values are your *data* (in which case posterior consistency is asking about $p_n \rightarrow \infty$ by definition) then you appear to be missing a layer of your model.  Please amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @Ben, I have edited my question.

Comment: @D.W., $f$ is the beta prime distribution.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus $\beta$ are the coefficients.

Comment: The use of $\beta_n$ and $\beta_i$ in the first two equations is still confusing. One needs to read the article to understand that $\beta_n$ is a vector and not just the same as $\beta_i$ with a different subscript.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reference I believe that you are estimating the vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ of size $p_n$ with a posterior distribution based on the observation of the vector $\mathbf{Y}$ of size $n$ in the model $$\mathbf{Y} =  \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}$$ where $\mathbf{X}$ is a fixed regression matrix $n \times p_n$ matrix. The components $\beta_i$ from the vector $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ have a prior distribution that follows the model that you described.

---

If you have a fixed $p$ then consistency seems guaranteed by a Bayesian law of large numbers, or consistency of likelihood/posterior for an i.i.d sample ([When do posteriors converge to a point mass?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490781/when-do-posteriors-converge-to-a-point-mass)). Or maybe I am missing something?

Say we use some fixed $p$ while letting $n$ increase, then the Bayesian posterior density $f(\boldsymbol{\beta}|\mathbf{Y})$ will concentrate near the true $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ (if the prior is not zero).

The same is true when $p$ is not fixed, but still with a finite upper bound. We can consider all $p$'s below the bound together while letting $n \to \infty$ and if they are all individually consistent, then we will also have consistency when we change $p$ while letting $n$ increase.

Comment: I don't think this answers OP question.

Comment: @Isaac I answered the question *"Is there a way to show posterior consistency for fixed/small $p$"* by explaining a way that it can be shown. Could you tell what is wrong with it?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, could you elaborate more about this? How will the theorem in [1] change with fixed/small $p$?

Comment: @MrDi for a *fixed* $p$ one can use the law of large numbers. When $p$ is not fixed then that approach becomes difficult because while we can have that for a larger $p$ the 'error' in the posterior may become larger. Then consistency is not obtained, if the increase in error due to increase in $p$ is faster than the decrease in error due to increase in $n$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, could you please reference some source where the  law of large numbers is used to prove posterior consistency for the normal-scale mixture model showen the question?

Comment: @MrDi I believe that the more formal approach uses martingales and was applied by Doob in 1949 in "Applications of the theory of martingales" but I can not find that source. You can also think of Lorraine Schwartz in [on Bayes procedures](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00535479) or [On Consistency of Bayes Procedures](https://www.jstor.org/stable/72077). The use of the law of large numbers I came up with (with help of a comment) 2 years ago, I do not know anymore how I did that. Yesterday I came across a similar approach in some sources that I was scanning but I lost it...

Comment: ... before using the law of large numbers in that linked question, I applied something that resembles a central limit theorem and that relates to the [Bernstein-von Mises theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%E2%80%93von_Mises_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just have two more subquestions so I can fully understand the full picture. When authors talk about "high-dimensionality" do they mean $p$ is large or $p$ is large with respect to $n$ (i.e. if $p$ is large but $n>p$ is that a high-dimensional regime)?. Secondly, could you please elaborate more on how "When p is not fixed then that approach becomes difficult because while we can have that for a larger p the 'error' in the posterior may become larger."?

Comment: @user3879021 Analogous example: Let $x_{mn} = \frac{m^2}{n}$. Then if $m$ is fixed we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{mn} = 0$ also if $m$ is not fixed but a function of $n$ that is bounded by a value $m_c$ then we have $0= \lim_{n\to \infty} x_{0n}\leq \lim_{n\to \infty} x_{mn} \leq  \lim_{n\to \infty} x_{m_cn} =0 $ . However if $m \to \infty$ then it might be that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, Ok thank you. what about the first question?

Comment: @user3879021 I am not sure whether 'high dimensionality' has a clear definition like $p >n$. But in this question I assumed that $p$ has a finite bound (because it is contrasted with  $p \to \infty$). In the setting of OLS/ridge/lasso regression then people do speak about high dimensionality if $p>n$, but I am not sure whether the same language is being used with these Bayesian problems. In the linked article form the question they speak about $p \gg n$ as 'the high dimensional setting'.