# Conditions needed for the convergence of Bayesian posterior distribution to point mass (posterior consistency)?

Tags: bayesian, convergence, consistency

The following 2 theorems (from Bayesian Data Analytics 3rd edition by Gellman, appendix B) show proofs for why Bayesian posteriors converge to a point mass around  θ<sub>0</sub>. Where θ<sub>0</sub> is the true parameter value or the value that minimises the KL divergence from the true data generating process, f(y). In these theorems the  θ could be a vector (so the model can have multiple parameters). I have 2 questions.

**Theorem one:**
[image]

**Theorem two:**
[image]

**Questions:**

Q1:
Why does the first theorem require the parameter space to be finite? What are the additional conditions (if any) needed for convergence when the state space is countably infinite?

Q2:
If we can extend the first theorem to account for countably infinite spaces, does that mean the second theorem can be extended to work for a continuous parameter space that is non-compact? If not what are the conditions needed for posterior convergence on a continuous non-compact parameter space.

Sextus Empiricus gave an answer similar to the proof I provided here: [When do posteriors converge to a point mass?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490781/when-do-posteriors-converge-to-a-point-mass) . Their answer doesn't state any restriction on the parameter space, but it looks like the proof they gave was for a discrete prior with a finite space.

Comment: Regarding your first question: there's a famous counter-example by Freedman in a nonparametric (infinite-dimensional) setting. Here's a [review chapter](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1880-7_10).